# bootstrap navbar doesnt stay top and width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason the navbar doesnt stay at top of the page. In other words, its scollable.
Heres my code:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("The Secured Password", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any reason it does that? Also, since i used navbar-inverse, the navbar has a black background. However, it's not all the way fit the screen. How can i make sure that it fits the whole screen? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to have it fixed to the top? as in, when you scroll the page you want it to stay there at all times and always be visible?

Comment: Yes exactly. I believe that's the natural behavior for bootstrap but for some reason i cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is the correct behavior of bootstrap or not (I've never used it), but you can get these things to act like you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/F7XH8/

```
    .navbar-wrapper { background: black; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; color: white; }
    .main { margin: 10em 0; }
```

I added ".main" so that it has content to scroll.

Comment: Thanks. I just realize the reason bootstrap didnt work is because i used a wrapper to wrap it and i didnt specific the position of the wrapper. On a follow-up question, now it works, but when i scoll, the content will come up and cover the navbar. How do I keep the navbar always on top of the page and also always on top of the content?

Comment: As far as bootstrap goes, I have no idea- however, you're looking for something called "z-index". The way it works: make sure your nav has a higher z-index then your content and set your content to "position: relative".. So to do this manually you would say "nav { z-index: 100; ...position: fixed; other code... } .content { position: relative; z-index: 50; }

Comment: @TitanTheYaphet Have you tried using Bootstrap's native functionality as I mention in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22800959/908491)? Using their native functionality will ensure your solution plays nicely with the rest of Bootstrap's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.navbar-fixed-top` and include a `.container` or `.container-fluid` to center and pad navbar content.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

From Bootstrap Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: The above is for Bootstrap v3.1.1. If you are using v2.3.2 go here instead: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar and scroll down to "Fixed to top". Apparently for the older version all you have to do is add `.navbar-fixed-top`.